# Multiple fields of specific class in another class

Tags: matlab, class, oop, properties, class-design

I am developing an object oriented program in MATLAB. I have a class called `MyNode` and a class called `MyService` as you see here:

```
classdef MyService
     % ......

end
```

```
classdef MyNode        
    properties
        MyNode     % List of neighbor Nodes

        MyService  % List of services that I request
        MyService  % List of services that I provide
    end

end
```

I want the class `MyNode` to have two instances of the `MyService` class, but I also want to have a list of `MyNode` objects in its definition. I know this code is not correct in MATLAB. How can I do that?

Comment: You can define a property to have any type, I don’t understand what the difficulty is? https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-properties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing property *names* with property *class specifications* (which are not required in MATLAB). In the code you wrote, you end up having *fields* with the **name** of `MyNode` and `MyService`, letting MATLAB assume what the datatype should be (probably `double` when uninitialized, and not what you wanted).

To fix this, please read the documentation page on [validating property values](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/validate-property-values.html). You will find that the way to specify the **class** for properties/fields is done using the following syntax:
[image]

In you case, this might look like this:

```
classdef MyNode        
    properties
        neighbors(:,1) MyNode    % List of neighbor Nodes
%       ^ name    ^ size   ^ class
        rService(1,1) MyService  % List of services that I request
        pService(1,1) MyService  % List of services that I provide
    end    
end
```

I would also advise adding some [constructors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/class-constructor-methods.html) to your classes.

Finally, I'd like to mention that I tested the above recursive class definition in R2018a. If your MATLAB version is fairly old (before R2016a), you can only use the syntax mentioned [here](https://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-class-property-types-2), roughly:

```
<varName>@<class> <scalar/vector/matrix> = <initial value>;
```

Comment: Thank you; my Matlab version is 2015b; so I knew why the syntax I used was error. I should use the old syntax.